# Tcpdump cross-compilation for MIPS

Tags: c, linux, mips

I have developed a basic "Hello World" cross-compilation for MIPS architecture. I have used CodeSourcery toolchain and compile it with the next command:

```
mips-linux-gnu-gcc -muclibc -mips32 -EB -static hallo.c
```

And it works, compile well and the target MIPS shows the "Hello World" sencence.

However, I want to compile tcpdump for MIPS architecture as well. The steps are:

```
Download and decompress libpcap
export LDFLAGS="-static"
CC=mips-linux-gnu-gcc ac_cv_linux_vers=2 ./configure --host=mips-linux-gnu --with-pcap=linux
make

Download and decompress tcpdump
CC=mips-linux-gnu-gcc ac_cv_linux_vers=2 ./configure --host=mips-linux-gnu --includedir=/to/the/path/libpcap --disable-ipv6
make
```

Both, libpcap and tcpump, compile well without any error. However, when I run tcpdump in the target MIPS -> no output, nothing, it doesn't work.

The file type of tcpdump binary is:

```
ELF 32-bit MSB  executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1, statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.12, not stripped
```

Although the target MIPS has a Linux version 2.6.8.1, I think the main difference between "Hello World" and tcpdump is the uClibc library, I don't know if it is necessary for compiling tcpdump, and I don't know how to include it.

Any idea?

Thanks, best regards.

Comment: Tried running it under `strace(1)` to see what really happens?

Comment: Hey DavidR, how are you going? Did you get any solution? I'm trying to compile a "tiny" tcpdump for mipsel as well